# win-JS how to interact with an item template

Tags: microsoft-metro

Hi how to get the click on the following div inside list view

```
<div class="labelBox" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
                <div onclick="checkClick()"></div>
            </div>-->
```

How to detect the onClick of the inner div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `win-interactive` is half correct.

Every thing lies in the place where you data bind the template and provide the data source to the list or flip etc.

there you need to use `WinJS.Utilities.markSupportedForProcessing` to interact with onclick

```
<div class="labelBox" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
                <div class="win-interactive" data-win-bind="onclick: test"></div>
            </div>-->
```

and where you data bind do :

```
test : WinJS.Utilities.markSupportedForProcessing(funcTest)
```

Comment: Yes it's working can you clarify the next doubt in the other question ?

Answer (score 2):

Mark it `win-interactive`

Here's a link to help you

[list view msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465496.aspx)

Search for win-interactive it you will get to know